# is anybody have idea in gwt celltree as a celltable column??? Because GWT does not have tree table

Tags: gwt

I want to use cell tree as a cell table column. because GWT does not have tree table. In my current project, I have to make feature like item and it's subitem in cell table. so it is not possible without tree table

If any body have idea of this then please help to make it possible.

Comment: You need to depend either on ExtGWT or SmartGWT for rich components.  Plain GWT has no such component.

Comment: Yes I know but I don't want to use ExtGWT Or SmartGWT. My project is only developed in core gwt so. I want to use cell tree as a cell table column. Refer link:                                                                                                      http://www.coderanch.com/t/573912/GWT/Adding-gwt-celltree-as-celltable  any Idea???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GWT 2.5 (to be released in a month or so) will add a `CellTableBuilder` that will let you generate additional rows; handling events on them will allow you to show/hide "child rows", mimicking a tree table.

Alternately, and withou waiting for 2.5, you can have your cells in a `CellTree` render columns (use a `CompositeCell` for flexibility and reuse). AFAICT thus is how Google Groups shows the unread count and menu for your favorite groups.

Comment: Thanks for reply. sure I will try to use Composite cell. but as I am not wrong then In google group, used cell tree for to show unread count. can u plz elaborate. >>how Google Groups shows the unread count and menu for your favorite groups.

Comment: OK, I'm not even sure Google Groups uses a `CellTree`, but it doesn't actually change much things; at https://groups.google.com/forum/, in the left pane (might require you to sign-in with your Google account to see a tree view there).

Answer (score 0):

I am trying build tree table with tree widget plus flextable only. With the help of both, I am able to create custom tree table widget.

http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Widgets~Tree

finally..I able to create custom tree table as requirement.